# Refused connection with Kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am new to Kubernetes, I tried to run some applications with Google Cloud and I am trying to understand how it works.

If I run:

```
kubectl get all
```

I obtain the following message:

```
E0122 15:57:30.513429   81051 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0122 15:57:30.513775   81051 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0122 15:57:30.515365   81051 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0122 15:57:30.515969   81051 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
E0122 15:57:30.517691   81051 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

**Why is that?** I would expect to have a clean minikube state. How can I clean it?

I tried running the same command with `sudo`, but I obtain the same result.

Comment: did you specify your `kubeconfig` in your config file?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: It looks like you have not installed a valid kubernetes configuration file. The address `http://localhost:8080/api` is what `kubectl` uses by default absent any configuration. [This document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) appears to have instructions for setting things up to work with google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This issue points at two potential things:

1. Your minikube is not actually running (check if docker is running)
2. Make sure your `kubeconfig` file is there. Normally, this is in `~/.kube/config`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The connection refused error indicates a Network communication issue. You need to dig deeper on what is the primary cause so to start off make sure that your Minikube is up and running. Then run ‘kubectl cluster-info’ to verify the status of the cluster. If everything looks good then check the Network configurations and make sure there are no issues with the communication. Firewall settings would be worth checking as well. Here is a documentation worth checking for reference.[1]

[1] https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/troubleshooting/